# How can I profile a Netlogo Model?

Tags: profiling, netlogo

Are there ways to profile netlogo code? Is there a way of getting the `time` not `ticks` in a section of the code so I can see where my code is running slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to test the speed code is run in netlogo. Consider the [profiler](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/profiler.html) extension.